# How do I setup my Golang API to receive an array of objects when Creating/POSTING a new entry? Is it possible to do it with map[string]interface?

Tags: rest, go, postman, mapping, crud

I’m a newbie to Go and I am having trouble getting my API that uses Gin to return the information correctly. I am using Postman to POST a new entry that creates a new UUID each time for the Phone object and an array of Logs objects. It is only returning the phone object’s information. The 2nd array of objects is coming back with 0 values and a 201 status created in Postman. I am only using the POST method.

I have refactored it many times and this is as close as I’ve gotten. I still don’t think it  allows me to possibly receive multiple log objects in the array as the response. How do I fix this? Is it possible to do this using map[string]interface{}?

## **This is my current code**

```
package main

import (
"net/http"
"time"

"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
"github.com/google/uuid"
)

// For id of log
type ID struct {
ID string `json:"id"`
}

// Phone Models
type Phone struct {
ID    string `json:"id"`
Model string `json:"model"`
Type  string `json:"type"`
}

type Logs struct {
Barcode        int       `json:"barcode"`
Created        time.Time `json:"created"`
Present        int       `json:"present"`
ElectricEnergy int       `json:"electricEnergy"`
Power          int       `json:"power"`
TimeCharged    int       `json:"timeCharged"`
AmountUsed     int       `json:"amountUsed"`
}

func createPhoneLog(c *gin.Context) {

var newDevice Phone
if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&newDevice); err != nil {
c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
return
}

phones := Phone{
ID:    newDevice.ID,
Model: newDevice.Model,
Type:  newDevice.Type,
}

var newPhoneRecord Logs
// if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&newPhoneRecord); err != nil {
// c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
// return
// }

r := &Logs{
Barcode:        newPhoneRecord.Barcode,
Created:        newPhoneRecord.Created,
Present:        newPhoneRecord.Present,
ElectricEnergy: newPhoneRecord.ElectricEnergy,
Power:          newPhoneRecord.Power,
TimeCharged:    newPhoneRecord.TimeCharged,
AmountUsed:     newPhoneRecord.AmountUsed,
}

type deviceWrapper struct {
ID    string `json:"id"`
Phone Phone  `json:"phone"`
Logs  Logs   `json:"logs"`
}

//Generate new UUID
var newDeviceLogID ID
newDeviceLogID.ID = uuid.New().String()

c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, &deviceWrapper{
ID:    newDeviceLogID.ID,
Phone: phones,
Logs:  *r,
})
}

func main() {
router := gin.Default()
router.POST("/", createPhoneLog)
router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")
}
```

`

## *This is what I see in Postman when making a Post*

[Postman Response for Create Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USbvP.png)

## **This is what I NEED to see as the response**

I want to be able to receive all of this information back in these objects all together in this format.

```
{
   "id": "PJDNSOfieC67GswNeUfYouhTSVS",
   "phone": {
   "id": "22DHOIRTNBKL5643",
   "model": "iPhoneX",
   "type": "1TB"
},
"logs": [
{
   "barcode": 12904HGJ3403,
   "created": 2,
   "present": 3,
   "electricEnergy": 4,
   "power": 5,
   "timeCharged": 1554,
   "amountUsed":54
},
 {
   "barcode": 129739394276,
   "created": 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z,
   "present": 5,
   "electricEnergy": 2,
   "power": 6,
   "timeCharged": 1127,
   "amountUsed":92
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new struct with the values you need to accept,just like your deviceWrapper。

example：

type res {
Id string `json:"id"`
Phone Phone `json:"phone"`
Logs []Log `json:"log"`
}